# embedded gists have extra line breaks

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, gist

I've embedded a github gist into my blog and the resultant code has some extra line breaks at the top and bottom that I would like to remove.  My blog uses css from the bootstrap project, and it also tweaks the font:

```
body {
    font: 100%/1.5 sans-serif;
}
```

I've [created this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W25px/3/) as a demo of the issue.

What's the best way to get rid of the breaks?  Should I be styling the embedded gist's font?  Thanks!

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: @Diodeus, thanks, that definitely makes sense.  I've rewrote the question based on a jsfiddle.

Comment: @MattBall are you still looking to sort it out? I have just created a fiddle. Its on the answer it self.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of different `line-height` in line numbers and code lines. And it is because you use relative `line-height`(that depends on font size) and different font sizes for line numbers(your font size) and line code (bootstrap overrides `font-size` and `line-height` for `pre` and `code` elements). To fix this you can reset bootstrap styles for github gists:

**UPD:**

```
.gist pre,
.gist code {
  font: inherit;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

proof: http://jsfiddle.net/W25px/8/

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Sody's answer where you have to reset the font, you have also to change the `white-space` property behaviour to align code and number lines.

With:

```
.gist pre,
.gist code {
    font: inherit;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Your gist should display perfectly: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhTUC/)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it is the line-height.  You will need to make sure that the line-height for the code listings line numbers matches the line-height for the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Please have a look on this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mee3/7C59m/)**

```
 /* Your Css */
     body {
           font: 100%/1.35 sans-serif;
     }
```

Did I get what you mean? The extra lines at the top and at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Add this style before body selector `* {line-height: normal;}`

See this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W25px/7/)**

you could also use `line-height: 100%` than normal (a little difference you will notice)

And as mentioned as in another answers, you could also use line-height there inside

```
.gist pre,
.gist code {
    line-height: 100%;
}
```

If this also doesn't solve your problem, margin or padding value may have been set. Modify that `margin: 0; padding: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the github gist embed script is misinterperting the 1.5 line height in an interesting way.

```
<div class="gist">
    <script src="https://gist.github.com/yosemitebandit/5295069.js?file=train.py">
    </script>
</div>

.gist {
    font:100%/1 sans-serif;
}
```

seems to be a simple fix.